# How to catch an "ReferenceError" with "onerror"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, referenceerror

I want my script to check many dependencies, and on success a submit button should appear. BUT if there was any kind of javascript error, the button should never appear. So I want to do at the end of my script something like:

```
if (typeof window.error_has_appeared == 'undefined') {
    button.classList.add("button_activated");
}
```

I have tried to solve my issue with window.onerror, but it seems not to catch all errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
   alert("ERROR");
};

window.onload = async function() {
   test
};
</script>
```

I can see in the javascript log: "ReferenceError: test is not defined". But why does the onerror alert not work?

Comment: so disable it inside of the function..... seems weird you would disable it for an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've made your `onload` handler an `async` function, so rather than being an unhandled error handled by the global error handler, the ReferenceError is an unhandled promise rejection, and so it's handled by the global promise rejection handler.

Since the `load` event code doesn't do anything with the promise returned by an async function, just make your function not `async`:

```js
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
   console.log("ERROR");
};

window.onload = function() {
   test
};
```

Or use `onunhandledrejection`:

```js
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
   console.log("onerror triggered");
};
window.onunhandledrejection = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
   console.log("onunhandledrejection triggered");
};

window.onload = async function() {
   test
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! It seems that this doesn't work with native Firefox, but in Google Chrome it does!

Comment: @Vidarrus - No worries! The first part (not using an `async` function) should work with Firefox. If you need `await`, you could always do this: `window.onload = function() { (async() => { /* Your code using `await` here */ })().catch(error => { /*flag the error*/}); };`

Comment: Thanks again, works perfect! For my described issue, I have just removed the "async" part, but if I need a async function I will use your commented code!